# Change Jquery fixed div to absolute when it reaches the bottom of the page

Tags: jquery, css

I have this Jquery code which what it does is to add a fixed class to a div when scrolling down.

Now what I'm trying to do is remove this fixed class when it reaches the bottom of the page and add a new one with `position:absolute;` and `margin-bottom:200px;` to avoid this box from being above the footer at the bottom of the page when it finishes scrolling.

You can see it here on the JsFiddle file to understand better what I'm trying to accomplish: http://jsfiddle.net/hcb4v21r/

```
$(document).on("scroll",function(){
    if($(document).scrollTop()>150){ 
        $("#item-nav").addClass("fixedProfileNav");
        }
    else{
        $("#item-nav").removeClass("fixedProfileNav");
        }
    });
```

---

I thounght that If I do something like this it would do the job but it doesn't work:

```
$(document).on("scroll",function(){
        if($(document).scrollTop()>80%){ 
            $("#item-nav").removeClass("fixedProfileNav");
            }
        else{
            $("#item-nav").addClass("fixedProfileNavBottom");
            }
        });
```

CSS

```
.fixedProfileNavBottom{
    position:absolute;
    margin-bottom:200px;
}
```

Something like removing the fixed class when it gets on 80/90 percent of the page but I don't know if this is the correct way to do it

Comment: Read [the manual](http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/). `.scrollTop()` returns an integer, not a percentage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider changing the line of code

```
if($(document).scrollTop()>80%){
```

to

```
if($(document).scrollTop()>(window.innerHeight * 0.85)){
```

or

```
if($(document).scrollTop()>($(document).innerHeight() * 0.85)){
```

or

```
if(($(document).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight)>($(document).innerHeight() * 0.85)){
```

Comment: Here's the thing, thing is only working for long scroll pages... for short scroll pages doesn't seem to work :\

Comment: You are using `if($(document).scrollTop()>($(document).innerHeight() * 0.85)){` ?